# Generics, V extends T, no error even if incompatible types

Tags: java, generics

I am new to generics. What I understand from below syntax is V should be same or subclass of T, however this shows no compile error and returns False even when V is Integer while T String array.

```
class GenMethDemo {

    public static <T ,V extends T> boolean isIn( T x, V[] y) {

        for ( int i =0; i< y.length; i++ ) 
            if ( x.equals(y[i]) ) return true;
        return false;

    }
}



public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String b[] = {"are", "how", "YOU"};

        System.out.println(GenMethDemo.isIn(1, b));

    }

}
```

However if I replace `<T,V extends T>` with `<T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T>` the behaviour is as expected.

Comment: `T` is treated as `Object` in this case, so `String[]` suits well.

Comment: Then what's the use of generics, aren't they for strong type safety. ?

Comment: at least at the runtime this should have shown an error, as T is now an integer. Also why it results in an error when using Comparable interface. Both string and integer are comparable.

Comment: Returning to your example: signature `static <T> boolean isIn(T x, T[] y)` is effective enough. `equals()` in most cases will work only for equal types.

Comment: *"as T is now an integer"*--`T` can be `Integer` as well as `Comparable<Integer>`, `Number`, `Serializable` and `Object`. Concrete type for `T` is selected considering types of other arguments too.

Comment: *"Both string and integer are comparable"*--types are incompatible, because `T` is `Comparable<Integer>`, not `Comparable<String>`. In this case, don't exist such combination for `T` and `V` which could satisfy both arguments.

Comment: Yes, you're right, `T` will be resolved as `? extends Object`. The only way to restrict type here is to declare it explicitly, e. g. to pass it as the third argument as `Class<T>`.

Comment: Thx, I do understand now, but using `static <T> boolean isIn(T x, T[] y)` would be same as `(Object x, Object[] y)`, what I intend here is type safety so that String and int aren't passed. Which I think could be achieved only by extending generic to their common interface.

Comment: *"You won't be able to pass String[]"* -  the object syntax works fine without any errors.

Comment: Yes :) my fault. Going to remove that comment

Comment: I get the following compile error if I type in your code: `Bound mismatch: The generic method isIn(T, V[]) of type GenMethDemo is not applicable for the arguments (Integer, String[]). The inferred type String is not a valid substitute for the bounded `

Comment: You must be using `<T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T>` which is expected to show error.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou you can answer, so I can accept.

Comment: @ujulu seems your compiler compliance level is 1.5...1.7

Comment: @Sasha Yes, my compiler at 1.7

Comment: @garg10may: This code *is* type-safe. There is no more "type-safety" to be gained from any further arbitrary restrictions.

Comment: How it's type safe, when I can pass Simultaneously String and Integer without any errors. ?

Comment: @garg10may: When you respond to a comment, please use @. You can pass String and Integer. What's unsafe about that? Does it cause a ClassCastException at runtime? If not, then it's type-safe. Java wouldn't compile it or would warn you if you did something not type-safe. The .equals() method exists on all objects, and accepts any object as argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java 5/6/7, passing `Integer` as `T` and `String` as `V` to such generic method would cause "bound mismatch" compiler error unless you explicitly cast first argument to `Object`.

In Java 8, due to [improved type inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html), to satisfy relationship between `T` and `V` for provided arguments, `T` is inferred as `? extends Object`, which allows `V` to be `String`, not resulting an error.

When you restrict to `<T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T>`, there is no such combination of types `T` and `V` which could satisfy `Integer` and `String`--even if `T` falls into the widest possible type `Comparable<Integer>`, it is not supertype of `String`. Thus you're getting compiler error as expected.